# Double value big enough returns an error in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I was basically playing with data types in order to learn java and here is what i am confused about.

```
double douVar = 30000000000.323262342134353;
int intVar = (int)douVar; // casting
System.out.println(intVar);
```

Now converting the `douVar` to string i overwrite the `double` variable:

```
douVar = 345839052304598; // returns an error: Integer number too long
System.out.println(Double.toString(douVar));
```

complete error:

```
Error:(20, 18) java: integer number too large: 345839052304598
```

I'm using IntellijIDEA compiler. I didnt try this over eclipse though but i assume the compiler would not be so different.
Does this mean that casting would result in modifying the original variable as well?

Comment: "casting would result in modifying the original variable as well"? What does that mean? Nothing will "happen" until you fix the compilation error.

Comment: Glad to see so many useful responses although not very satisfied with the downvote or perhaps someone can explain why i got the downvote.

Comment: I would guess a down vote may have occurred because your question title did not actually have anything to do with your actual question.

Comment: Being a beginner in Java, i thought casting changed the dataype of original variable. Thats how i interpreted and the answers clarified things for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, constant numbers without a decimal are ints by default. 
There are 2 ways to change the constant definition to a double:

1. Add a `d` or `D` at the end.
2. Add a `.0` at the end

```
douVar = 345839052304598d;
douVar = 345839052304598.0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Java interprets `345839052304598` as an integer.

In Java an Integer is 4 bytes long and therefore has a value range from `–2 147 483 648` to `2 147 483 647`. (your number is obviously not in that range)

To make Java treat the number as a double, you must write:

```
double d = 345839052304598D;
/* or */
double d1 = 345839052304598.0;
```

(Same goes for a `long`, you have to write `L` instead of `D` in that case)

Answer (score 3):

The literal **345839052304598** will be considered as an `integer` by the `compiler`, since this value is to large for an integer, a compile time error is thrown. Therefore you need to tell the compiler that the value you want to use is actually double value, that you can do the following way:

```
douVar =345839052304598D; // note D at the end which tells comipler that it is double
```

Comment: okay i get this. Can you please tell me then why didnt it return an error in this statement: `double douVar = 30000000000.323262342134353;` this also seems to be a value larger than the much integer can hold.

Comment: When you used 30000000000.323262342134353 compiler will detect a decimal point which means a double value.

Comment: @DarshanLila The default data type with a `.` present in a numeric constant is `double`, not `float`.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare number as 345839052304598 compiler tries to read it as a 32 bit integer. But since this exceed the range of int compiler throws the error. 
You can use d, D or L suffix or add decimal place like .0 to to handle this,

Answer (score 1):

Just change `douVar = 345839052304598;` to `douVar = 345839052304598.00;`

Comment: One `.0` is enough. Another option is adding `d` or `D` suffix after number to change it to `double`.